# Colors in Man Pages

Tags: colors, less, man, pager, termcap

When I look at a man page in my 'console' (not an `xterm`) I see some coloration, but I don't get this in my `xterm`'s (e.g. `konsole`) is there any way I can enable this? hopefully a fairly simple solution?

Comment: Wow, I just realized that this is one of the earliest questions on this site (119th), and it was asked on the first day of this site. It's kinda amazing and sad that the accepted solution from 12 years ago is still the best solution, and there aren't better alternatives!

Comment: Note that man pages are basically just plain text with some bold and underline added. There are no hyperlinks (at least not explicitly). So you don't _need_ colors to see all the features man pages are written with. Not to say there is anything wrong at all with colorizing man pages. It's just an aesthetic choice.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need to use the [`termcap(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/termcap) feature. The man page on some Unices says this tool is obsolete and to use [`terminfo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo), but it's still available on [others](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=termcap&sektion=5) (and `terminfo` is more complicated).

More importantly, `less` uses `termcap`.

---

### Setting colors for `less`

I do the following so that `less` and `man` (which uses `less`) will have color:

```shell
$ cat ~/.LESS_TERMCAP 
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(tput bold; tput setaf 2) # green
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(tput bold; tput setaf 6) # cyan
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(tput sgr0)
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(tput bold; tput setaf 3; tput setab 4) # yellow on blue
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(tput rmso; tput sgr0)
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(tput smul; tput bold; tput setaf 7) # white
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(tput rmul; tput sgr0)
export LESS_TERMCAP_mr=$(tput rev)
export LESS_TERMCAP_mh=$(tput dim)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZN=$(tput ssubm)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZV=$(tput rsubm)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZO=$(tput ssupm)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZW=$(tput rsupm)
export GROFF_NO_SGR=1         # For Konsole and Gnome-terminal
```

And then in my `~/.bashrc`, I do this:

```shell
# Get color support for 'less'
export LESS="--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS"

# Use colors for less, man, etc.
[[ -f ~/.LESS_TERMCAP ]] && . ~/.LESS_TERMCAP
```

**NOTE:** See [*Documentation on `LESS_TERMCAP_*` variables?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/documentation-on-less-termcap-variables) for how this works.

### The final result

[image: ss of man page]

Comment: I believe the reason this works the way it does, is because 'console' translates 'underline' into colour, where-as X11 stuff supports underlines. You can test this theory by typing `echo -e "\e[04mhello world\e[0m"` in both the console and your X11 terminal and seeing the difference.  So this above hack *abuses* termcap to lie to LESS about what codes it needs to emit for bold/underline and forces it to produce colour escape codes instead.

Comment: Indeed, the translation of underline into blue has historic reasons, going back to the text modes of the original PC graphics adapters MDA and CGA (actually the CGA text modes are still available to date). Those graphics adapters stored two bytes per character: One holding the ASCII code, one holding the attributes. The MDA interpreted the attribute byte as combinations of underline, bright, blinking and inverse, while the CGA interpreted that byte as foreground and background colour. And it happened that the MDA attribute for underline equalled the CGA attribute for blue on black.

Comment: This doesn't work in Konsole or Gnome-terminal. I set them, and the only colour change is for the cursor and the status page. I turns out I need: `export GROFF_NO_SGR=1`.

Comment: Well, this used to work in Gnome Terminal, but it's been a while since I wrong these instructions so it's possible that something has changed.

Comment: Works for me on `tmux` in `uxterm`. Thanks!

Comment: That's a lot of sub-shells created. What is the advantage over this [simpler approach](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329092/143394)?

Comment: Please update your answer to advice setting `export GROFF_NO_SGR=1` as mentioned by @CMCDragonkai unless your answer does not work on konsole, gnome-terminal, terminology... Cheers

Comment: @TomHale, mainly cross-system/terminal compatibility (and the ability to share the script with others in a way that's unambiguous). If you ever find yourself working on a box that uses different control codes, and you scp/rsync your shell profile over to it, when the control codes are all hard-coded like in that example, they may not work as expected on the destination machine, and you could end up with garbled output. Of course, if the script will only ever run on one or two known machines/terminal-emus, then the hard-coded approach is just fine.

Comment: This one works better than the Arch Linux Wiki implementation, reusable, nice. Thanks!

Comment: Just to added to the last comment, it works along with Arch Wiki way very well, even better. Tested on Fedora 32, Ubuntu 20.04 and Arch Linux / Manjaro ;-)

Comment: Regarding `ZN` and `ssubm`, etc: less doesn't use `ZN`, and the other subscript-related capabilities (which are defined in the `mintty` description).

Comment: And less doesn't actually ***use*** termcap on any system you're likely to be using.  Just the termcap *interface* to terminfo.

Comment: Isn't this better: `MANPAGER="less -R --use-color -Dd+r -Du+b"`? It turns bold text to red color and underlined text to blue color. It's suggested in [Bruce's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673545/68762). It seems to be cleaner and much simpler than messing with the termcap sequences.

Answer (score 29):

The default underlines hurt my eyes. This setup greatly improves my `man` page reading:

[image: Coloured man page example]

Add the following in your `~.bashrc':

```
# Have less display colours
# from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console#man
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[1;31m'     # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;33m'     # begin blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;44;37m' # begin reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[01;37m'    # begin underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m'        # reset bold/blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m'        # reset reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m'        # reset underline
export GROFF_NO_SGR=1                  # for konsole and gnome-terminal
```

For the win, combine with `export MANPAGER='less -s -M +Gg'` [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19871578/5353461) to display your percentage into the document.

Comment: As @CMCDragonkai mentioned in a comment on another answer, this requires `export GROFF_NO_SGR=1` to work on some terminal emulators.

Comment: For the win!!  I love the % display `export MANPAGER='less -s -M +Gg'` adds.

Comment: During search this does not highlights the selected work in different color, is it possible to have?

Comment: How can I also change the color for the echo area as well (bottom section?) Mine's background is purple and its unreadable .

Answer (score 18):

You can solve this issue by using a different pager, for example `most`. `man` will actually use the program specified in the `PAGER` environment variable. From the **man(1)** man page:

> **MANPAGER, PAGER**
>
> If  $MANPAGER  or  $PAGER  is  set ($MANPAGER is used in preference), its value is used as the name of the program used to display the manual page.  By default, pager -s is used.
>
> The value may be a simple command name or a command with arguments, and may use shell quoting (backslashes, single quotes, or double quotes).
>
> It  may not  use  pipes  to  connect  multiple commands; if you need that, use a wrapper script, which may take the file to display either as an argument or on standard input.

If `most` is installed on your system, try this, before launching `man`:

```
export PAGER=most
```

Comment: `most` should be installed, for this to work.

Comment: `most` has strange keybindings... which are not configurable.

Answer (score 13):

If you use [Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/), you can add `colored-man-pages` to the `plugins` array in your `.zshrc` file.

Comment: using `colored-man-pages` freezes my man page during search

Comment: You should tell its developers about that.

Answer (score 5):

**Save 'most' persistently**

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

1. Install 'most'.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install most
   ```
2. edit .bashrc , type:

   ```
   nano ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. Add these lines:

   ```
   # color man-pages persistently
   export PAGER='most'
   ```
4. Save

   (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> -> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)
5. Refresh

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
6. Test

   ```
   man ln
   ```

This also works in xterm.

Comment: to avoid opening nano, you can append to bashrc from the terminal:

    sudo apt install most;
    echo "export PAGER='most'" >> ~/.bashrc;
    source ~/.bashrc

Comment: This has the disadvantage of setting your pager to `most` for all uses of pagers. It would be better to use `export MANPAGER='most'` if you only want to change your pager for man pages.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, you could try the following `MANPAGER` settings [1]. The second one needs [`bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat).

```
MANPAGER="less -R --use-color -Dd+r -Du+b"
```

or

```
MANPAGER="sh -c 'col -bx | bat -l man -p'"
```

On Gentoo Linux, you could also try this, which needs [`app-text/manpager`](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/app-text/manpager)

```
MANPAGER=manpager
```

(I didn't read the code of `manpager`, I guess it is just a wrapper of the command `less` and the environment variables `LESS_TERMCAP_??`).

[1] https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Man_page#Color_for_man_pages

Comment: I like this solution the most (specifically the first suggestion). It seems to be cleaner and much simpler than messing with termcap sequences in `LESS_TERMCAP_*` environment variables. Moreover it allows to combine bold and underlined text with colors (instead of replacing them). Are there any downsides?

Comment: I, too, like the 1st suggestion here more than the presently most-upvoted answer from 2010 (which I've been using for years) because it doesn't need subshells and its effects are limited solely to man(1) pages via the MANPAGER env var. Upvoted. Thanks for cluing me into the existence of less(1)' `-Dx` option! For posterity: `MANPAGER='less --use-color -Dd+c -DPYb -DSYb'` more-or-less re-creates the colors of the 2010 answer for those who prefer its "historical" MDA/CGA-inspired scheme. Even more spartanly: `MANPAGER='less -Duc'` can make X11 and console man pages more visually consistent. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Taking [dirtybit’s answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/125), I wanted to change the color of highlighted
search results. This is called "standout mode", here is an example file
"xterm-yellow.ti":

```sh
xterm-yellow|yellow standout mode,
# exit standout mode
  rmso=\e[m,
# begin standout mode
  smso=\e[5;30;43m,
# similar terminal
  use=xterm,
```

Compile and install the file:

```
tic xterm-yellow.ti
```

Add line to "~/.profile" or similar:

```
TERM=xterm-yellow
```

Comment: `tic: Can't open xterm-yellow.ti
`

Comment: I pasted into a file called `xterm-yellow.ti` but now I get following error  `"xterm-yellow.ti", line 8, col 2, terminal 'xterm-yellow': Illegal character (expected alphanumeric or @%&*!#) - '^?'`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/569-colored-manpages.html

**Excerpt:**

```
$ mkdir ~/.terminfo/ && cd ~/.terminfo
```

Now get the `terminfo` description (save the following as mostlike.txt):

```
# Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-pcolor
mostlike|manpages with color looking like most, 
    am, hs, km, mir, msgr, xenl, 
    cols#80, it#8, lines#24, wsl#40, 
    acsc=``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~, 
    bel=^G, bold=\E[1m\E[31m, clear=\E[H\E[2J, cr=^M, 
    csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H, 
    cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C, 
    cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A, 
    dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM, dl1=\E[M, 
    dsl=\E]0;\007, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, enacs=\E)0, fsl=^G, 
    home=\E[H, ht=^I, hts=\EH, il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=^J, 
    is2=\E7\E[r\E[m\E[?7h\E[?1;3;4;6l\E[4l\E8\E>, kbs=^H, 
    kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA, 
    kdch1=\E[3~, kf1=\E[11~, kf10=\E[21~, kf11=\E[23~, 
    kf12=\E[24~, kf13=\E[25~, kf14=\E[26~, kf15=\E[28~, 
    kf16=\E[29~, kf17=\E[31~, kf18=\E[32~, kf19=\E[33~, 
    kf2=\E[12~, kf20=\E[34~, kf3=\E[13~, kf4=\E[14~, 
    kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~, 
    kfnd=\E[1~, kich1=\E[2~, kmous=\E[M, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~, 
    kslt=\E[4~, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m\E[34m, ri=\EM, rmacs=^O, 
    rmcup=\E[2J\E[?47l\E8, rmir=\E[4l, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>, 
    rmso=\E[m, rmul=\E[m, 
    rs2=\E7\E[r\E8\E[m\E[?7h\E[?1;3;4;6l\E[4l\E>, sc=\E7, 
    sgr0=\E[m, smacs=^N, smcup=\E7\E[?47h, smir=\E[4h, 
    smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smso=\E[1;30m\E[47m, smul=\E[32m, 
    tbc=\E[3g, tsl=\E]0;, u6=\E[%i%d;%dR, u7=\E[6n, 
    u8=\E[?1;2c, u9=\E[c,
```

Now compile it using `tic` (the terminfo entry-description compiler):

```
$ tic mostlike.txt
```

(You may want to delete the `mostlike.txt` file after compiling.)

And then just define an alias in the `*rc` file of your favorite shell.

```
$ alias man="TERMINFO=~/.terminfo/ LESS=C TERM=mostlike PAGER=less man"
```

If you want to modify the terminfo file, use `infocmp mostlike` to get the content of it later.

Comment: It helps if you summarize the source here, so people can see what it says without having to click through (and in case the site ever goes down)

Comment: Please provide answers, not just links to answers. It's very  good to provide links which support your answer, however. Imagine I was Googling for this question--- a good answer at StackExchange will quickly find it's way to the first page of results.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Found this [`mostlike.txt`](http://uploads.askapache.com/2010/03/mostlike.txt) online.

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: It's intended to show bold as bright-red, and underline as green.  But I wouldn't use it as written.