# Extra characters appear in `less`

Tags: terminal, man, escape-characters, less

Many non alpha-numeric characters appear as jumbled mess when using `less` and `man`.
Currently, I'm using `zsh` but the same problem happens in `bash` and `sh`.
The problem also appears in both the `st` and `termite` terminal emulators.

`man grep` produces:

[image: Broken man page]

How can i fix this?

`env -i TERM=$TERM PATH=/usr/bin:/bin HOME=/none man grep` renders correctly.

Comment: it is not a jumbled mess ... those are VT100 commands that tell the terminal window how to format the displayed text ... your terminal program does not understand the commands

Comment: I get the same issue in `xterm` as well.

Comment: If `less -R` works, add `export LESS=-R` to your `~/.bashrc`. Read `man less`.

Comment: it may be a messed up prompt doing this (PS1) ... does the same thing happen if you log in as root?

Comment: @waltinator, the `man-db` implementation of `man` should already set `$LESS` to something like `-ix8RmPm`. Also, these days, those escape sequences tend not to be used by default (you'd need to set the `GROFF_SGR` env var), so there's something unusual in the OP's environment. See also [Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/371067)

Comment: What distribution are you running? Have you made any configuration that you think might affect how `man` or `less` works? Does `env -i TERM=$TERM PATH=/usr/bin:/bin HOME=/none man grep` show the man page correctly, with or without formatting, in less or something else?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yes, `env -i TERM=$TERM PATH=/usr/bin:/bin HOME=/none man grep` renders correctly. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem disappears with a minimal environment, it's caused by an environment variable. It [turns out to be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/619184) your [`LESS_TERMCAP`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/documentation-on-less-termcap-variables) settings. You've set them to sequences beginning with `[`. They're missing the initial escape character.

```
csi=$(printf '\033[')
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb="${csi}1;31m"
…
```

Answer (score 0):

These vars were exported in my `~/.profile`. Removing them solved the issue.

```
export LESS=-R
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb="$(printf '%b' '[1;31m')"
export LESS_TERMCAP_md="$(printf '%b' '[1;36m')"
export LESS_TERMCAP_me="$(printf '%b' '[0m')"
export LESS_TERMCAP_so="$(printf '%b' '[01;44;33m')"
export LESS_TERMCAP_se="$(printf '%b' '[0m')"
export LESS_TERMCAP_us="$(printf '%b' '[1;32m')"
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue="$(printf '%b' '[0m')"
```