# Rsync directory filtering out files and retaining edge cases (e.g. names w/ hyphen (-) chars)

Tags: bash, sed, rsync, ls

I have a test folder with the following structure:

```
"driveA"
  - "bar - foo"
    - "fileBarFooA"
    - "fileBarFooB"
  - "fileA"
  - "fileB"
  - "fileC"
  - "folder.A"
    - "fileAA"
    - "fileAB"
  - "folderB"
    - "fileBA"
    - "fileBB"
```

Within a bash shell, I want to rsync driveA's contents into driveB EXCEPT for folder "folder.A", to get a resulting copy that looks like:

```
"driveB"
  - "bar - foo"
    - "fileBarFooA"
    - "fileBarFooB"
  - "fileA"
  - "fileB"
  - "fileC"
  - "folderB"
    - "fileBA"
    - "fileBB"
```

At first glance, one approach to do this is by providing a filtered ls on the driveA as an argument into rsync:

```
rsync -aR -- `ls -F | grep [^folder.A/]` ../driveB
```

This results in errors and doesn't complete:

[image: filtered rsync first approach error]

The problem is folder "bar - foo" doesn't get copied. Looking at the error, we see that one problem is that we're feeding `ls -F` which outputs non-escaped output of filenames and folders:

```
:driveA$ ls -F
bar - foo/  
fileA       
fileB       
fileC
folder.A/
folderB/
```

I haven't found a option in `ls` to make it output with escape chars, so instead the next thing to try is post-processing with `sed` - one way is to add escape chars:

```
:driveA vgani$ ls -F | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g' | grep [^folder.A/]
bar\ -\ foo/
fileA
fileB
fileC
folderB/
```

Rsyncing with this gives:

```
:driveA $ rsync -aR `ls -F | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g' | grep [^folder.A/]` ../driveB
rsync: -\: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/main.c(1337) [client=2.6.9]
```

Oh no, an error (and a 1337 one at that!) This is just due to rsync taking in the `-\` part of the folder as a command-line argument, so we can fix that by adding in `--`:

```
driveA $ rsync -aR -- `ls -F | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g' | grep [^folder.A/]` ../driveB
```

[image]

So it looks like the same result as not even bothering with adding escape chars.

Another post-processing idea would be to try adding quotation marks instead:

```
:driveA $ ls -F | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/[^/]$/"/g' | sed 's/\//"\//g'
"bar - foo"/
"file"
"file"
"file"
"folder.A"/
"folderB"/
```

But this leads to rsync treating the quotations as literal charaters and copies nothing:

```
:driveA $ rsync -aR -- `ls -F | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/[^/]$/"/g' | sed 's/\//"\//g' | grep [^\"folder.A\"/]` ../driveB
rsync: link_stat "/driveA/"bar" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/driveA/-" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/driveA/foo"/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/driveA/"file"" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/driveA/"file"" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/driveA/"file"" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/driveA/"folderB"/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

So far I'm stumped, is there a way to feed `rsync` contents of `ls` without choking on hyphen characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsync has an `exclude` option. You should be able to achieve this with:

```
cd /path/to/driveA
rsync -avWxP --exclude=folder.A . /path/to/driveB/
```

Comment: A bit shocked i failed to notice that in the man pages. thanks!

Comment: @VivekGani, you might want to read the `less` man page—`less` is the default pager for `man`.  In particular, there is a "search" command (type `/`).  Also, [some tips](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1841/135943).

Comment: Thanks, aware of using `less`, think i was using the wrong search term (think I was searching for "ignore" instead of "exclude") at the time.