# How to use the man command to navigate to specific sections of the manual?

Tags: man, options

I would like to know if there are easier ways to navigate to specific sections of manual pages such as **Examples** or **Options**

I currently resort to piping `man` to regex find and retrieve statements.

For example to find the entry for the `-f` option in the `grep` manual I use this statement:

`man grep | grep -A 2 -e '-f'`

Is there a better way to use man? I've been able to find scant info on the `-S` option but perhaps I'm going down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: Strongly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96231/117549

Comment: Look at  here: [Tricks and tips for finding information in man pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1841/109397). The answer to your question specifically: [The default pager for reading a man page is less...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2001/109397)

Comment: thanks for the results guys, these didn't come up in my search for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I usually use
`/<search pattern>`

 after opening a specific man page

As MiniMax mentioned the pager is less by default.