# Colored man pages not working on gentoo

Tags: colors, man, gentoo, less, termcap

I have a problem using [**these methods**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages) to get colors in my man pages in gentoo. I've asked already in the gentoo forums but it still doesn't work, and the comments in a bug report ([Bug 184604](http://bugs.gentoo.org/184604)) don't work either. Can someone help me to get colours in my man pages?

**EDIT**:
Yes, I'm using less as pager and urxvt-unicode as terminal emulator

**EDIT2**:

I already asked in the gentoo forums but it didn't help, this is the link: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-819833-start-0.html.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using, and what does `echo $TERM` display?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Could be a number of problems.

Seeing as you're using `zsh`, try putting this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;31m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;47;34m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[01;32m'
export LESS=-r
```

Then open a new terminal window and try running

```
man ls
```

if it's not working, run each of the following to find out where the problem is:

---

**Number 1**

```
typeset -p LESS_TERMCAP_md | cat -v
```

should print

```
typeset -x LESS_TERMCAP_md="^[[01;31m"
```

and

```
typeset -p LESS
```

should print

```
typeset -x LESS="-r"
```

if not, you put the `export LESS` stuff in the wrong file.

---

**Number 2**

```
echo "${LESS_TERMCAP_md}red${LESS_TERMCAP_me}"
```

should print

```
red
```

in a red color.  If it doesn't there is something wrong with your terminal settings.  Check your terminal settings (e.g. `~/.Xresources`) or try running `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` and see if that works.

---

**Number 3**

```
echo -E "a^Ha" | LESS= less -r
```

(`^H` must be entered by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)

should print

```
a
```

in red.   If it doesn't, please run these

```
type less
less --version
```

and paste the output back in your question.

---

**Number 4**

```
bzcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.bz2 | \
    /bin/sh /usr/bin/nroff -mandoc -Tutf8  | head -n 5 | cat -v
```

should print

```
LS(1)                            User Commands                           LS(1)



N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE
```

(note the `^H` like in step number 3)

if it's printing something like:

```
LS(1)                            User Commands                           LS(1)



^[[1mNAME^[[0m
```

instead, you will need to find a way to disable "sgr escape sequences".  The easiest thing to try is adding `export GROFF_NO_SGR=1` to `.zshrc`, but there are other ways of fixing this.

---

**Number 5**

```
bzcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.bz2 | \
    /bin/sh /usr/bin/nroff -mandoc -Tutf8 | less
```

should display the `ls` man page with colors.

---

```
man ls
```

should now be working!

Comment: I'm using zsh, I couln't post this before because I was a new user http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-819833-start-0.html also typeset -p LESS printed this: "typeset: no such variable: LESS" and about the number 5, there's no ls.1.gz but there's ls.1.bz2 but it prints this "gzip: /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.bz2: not in gzip format" the rest of the options work well but I still don't have coloured man pages.

Comment: `typeset -p LESS` not working is your problem.  But seeing as you are using `zsh`, you should put `export LESS=-r` in your `~/.zshrc`, not in `~/.bashrc`.  Please do that then try these steps again.

Comment: And change `zcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz` to `bzcat /usr/share/man/man1/ls1.bs2`.

Comment: I have updated the instructions based on the information you just provided.

Comment: I added export LESS=-r but number 5 prints a normal man page with no colours.

Comment: I tried the new options and all of them work except the last one, it prints the man pages with no colours.

Comment: Really?  Even in a new terminal?  What does `typeset -p LESS` print in that window?  But does `man ls` give colors?  That's obviously the main thing.

Comment: typeset -p LESS returns typeset -x LESS=-r but man ls doesn't give colours.

Comment: I have added a new number 4: `bzcat`... `| head -n 5 | cat -v`

Comment: it prints 
LS(1)                            User Commands                           LS(1)



^[[1mNAME^[[0m

Comment: We have found your problem!

Comment: First thing to try: change `/bin/sh /usr/bin/nroff -mandoc -Tutf8` to `/bin/sh /usr/bin/nroff -mandoc -Tutf8 -c` above.

Comment: now it returns LS(1)                            User Commands                           LS(1)



N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE

Comment: Cool.  There's many things the problem could be, but my best guess: try putting `export GROFF_NO_SGR=1` in your `.zshrc`, open a new terminal, and try `man ls` again.

Comment: If this doesn't work, I will need you to do some reading, and to think if you changed any `USE` variable or environment variable (e.g. an `export` line in your `.zshrc` or other config file) related to `color` or `sgr` or `man` or `nroff` or `groff` or `grotty`.

Comment: PS: When it prints `N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE`, you should be able to pipe that to `less` by adding `| less` at the end, and you should see the colors.  So we are aiming to have `nroff` produce this `N^HN`... output by default.

Comment: `GROFF_TYPESETTER`, `GROFF_NO_SGR`, `LESSCHARSET`, `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, `man.conf`, and `--enable-sgr` are the the main things we need to look for.

Comment: export GROFF_NO_SGR=1 worked, thank you, could you point me to some references on this? you were the only one who actually gave a different answer.

Comment: Most of it's based on things I have learned over many years, e.g. `man` runs `nroff`; old systems would make letters bold by printing the letter, backspacing, then printing the letter again, like a printer that uses ink would (printing the letter twice makes the letter darker); information about `LESS_TERMCAP_md` is under `md` in `man 5 terminfo`, and searching for "xterm color escape sequences".  For the last part, my references were the man pages for `less`, `nroff`, `groff`, and `grotty`.  And of course, `zsh` commands to run for every `zsh` shell should go in `.zshrc`.

Comment: There is also `tput(1)`, perhaps this command provides an alternative way to change the terminal's behaviour, but I couldn't get this command to do anything. Perhaps someone more knowledegable can provide more clues. But the env var works for me, thanks!

Comment: @mikel Thanks a lot for `GROFF_NO_SGR=1`; it fixed grotty 1.23 breaking man page colours after a recent (2023 Jul) update. It used to work up till 1.22.4 (2023 Mar) without the env variable.

Answer (score 4):

Having read Mikels answer, its very comprehensive, and will hopefully work on all systems, but its probably overkill for myself ( also on a gentoo system. )

So here is a result for people who are very "Do long, didn't read" with all that shenanigans.

The Bare minimum I could do to get Coloured Man pages is as follows:

```
LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;31m' LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m' GROFF_NO_SGR=1 man man
```

This renders text that was previously only in bold, in bold *and red*. ( The red characterised by the '31' in `LESS_TERMCAP_md` )

```
LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m' LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;32m'
```

These 2 rules control the formatting of the current line number display, and coerce it to rendering in Green.

```
LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[04;33m' LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'
```

These 2 rules move everything that was previously underlined, to being underlined *and yellow*. ( 04 is 'underlined', 33 is "yellow" )

Answer (score 0):

People searching for solutions to this in 2023 might be affected by a change in the groff package introduced in version 1.23.0.

Putting `export MANROFFOPT=-c` in my `.zshrc` fixed it for me.

(or alternatively `GROFF_NO_SGR=1`)

Background:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=287185

https://github.com/jedsoft/most/issues/18