# How to get colours on man pages with w3m as a PAGER?

Tags: pager, w3m

Is it possible, and if so how, to have colour/**bold**/*italic* characters in `man` pages while using [`w3m`](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/)?

Another pager ([`most`](http://www.jedsoft.org/most/)) does have some limited colour support but is not as versatile as `w3m`.  I know that [`less`](http://www.gnu.org/software/less/) does have colour support as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119/10526).

Comment: May depend on the `man` implementation you use. `man` from the _mandb_ package has a `--html` switch. When using it `$BROWSER` is used for paging instead of `$MANPAGER` or `$PAGER`.

Comment: @manatwork: I did not know that.  This is quiet nice but still no colours... I feel that I should up vote your contribution! ^_~

Comment: The man pages will still be formatted with bold and italic. Try `lynx`. It colors bold in red and italic in blue. (Not sure, but I think those are configurable.) `BROWSER=lynx man -H man`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zIRaw.png

Comment: Short form of `--html` with mandb is `-H` ;) Lynx is a good idea.

Comment: The colors are configurable; go to `O)ptions`, scroll to the bottom to where it says "View the file lynx.cfg" -> "color-style configuration".  Except you can't edit lynx.cfg in lynx, lol.  The system wide is `/etc/lynx.cfg`. @manatwork : You should put this up as an answer, it's great.

Comment: How is [this not colour support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages) in `less`?

Comment: *Why* would one use `w3m` as *pager* for a manual page? Are you talking about HTML manual pages? Also: Not `less` has color support, but the *terminal*. `less` can only send control sequences to the terminal to make that switch colors. Finally: Manual pages do not use colors; they use attributes like bold, underline, or italics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the answer you were looking for, but it might be a better one.

`mandb` is an implementation of `man` that will format man pages in HTML.  It was written by someone at Redhat and is I think now the standard on all `.rpm` based systems, but available to install as a replacement for the old man on Debian, Ubuntu, et. al.

Using mandb, `man -H whatever` will format the page in HTML and send it to `$BROWSER`.  There are a few man pages where this goes screwy (such as `gcc`), but most of them are fine. It's also sometimes problematic with `google-chrome`.

That's a great feature, but most of the time I can't be bothered -- I'd rather just glance through the page in a terminal.  Thanks to `lynx`, a text mode web browser, you can sort of get the best of both worlds.  I don't want `$BROWSER` to be lynx generally, so:

```
#!/bin/bash

BROWSER=lynx
man -H $@
```

And call this `mnlx` or something.  `mandb` creates a tmp file to do this, so you could speed things up by caching the HTML versions and using those when available  -- but that's a longer script...

The really nice thing about this is `mandb` also **adds an index with links to each section** at the top, e.g.:

```
                           BASH                BASH (p1 of 121)
   NAME
   SYNOPSIS
   COPYRIGHT
   DESCRIPTION
   OPTIONS
   ARGUMENTS
   INVOCATION
   DEFINITIONS
   RESERVED WORDS
   SHELL GRAMMAR
   COMMENTS
   QUOTING
   PARAMETERS
   EXPANSION
   REDIRECTION
   ALIASES
   FUNCTIONS
   [...]
```

The man page proper follows this.  As manatwork indicates in the comments, italic and bold appear as red and (bold) blue in lynx; normal text is white, links are green, the current link is bold yellow.

Comment: +1. Not the direct answer to my question but still a great answer to my problem!  Thank you.

Comment: I think this answer is rather wrong: `mandb` does not format manual pages; `groff` (`nroff`, `troff`) does. As the manual page for `man` states: "*This option will cause groff to produce HTML output*..."

Comment: That's the `mandb` man page, right?   Ie., `mandb` *uses* `groff` to produce HTML, because of course man pages in their source form use groff/troff formatting.  While this is interesting and perhaps of significance in some contexts, I don't see how delving into the details of the implementation are relevant here, just a simple explication of the interface.