# Arrow keys in `less`

Tags: linux, debian, less

In the manpage of `less` the up- and down-arrow keys aren't mentioned in the context of normal navigation, yet on Debian Linux (8.2) they obviously work to scroll up and down. Why is this? A lesskey file is mentioned in the manpage, maybe it is defined there?
I can't find this file anywhere, does it exist in the standard installation of Debian?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The manual page, e.g, as you might find on [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/less.1.html) or [Unix commands](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/less.htm) is incomplete:

- Among other things, `less` initializes itself using the termcap strings for the cursor keys, home/page keys, pageup/pagedown keys.
- In most configurations, it is also possible to override the termcap settings with environment variables beginning `LESS_TERMCAP_`, e.g., `LESS_TERMCAP_ku` to override the `ku` (cursor-up) string.

Looking at the source code, there's a table `cmdtbl` in `decode.c` which gives initial key-bindings, e.g.,

```
    'k',0,                          A_B_LINE,
    'y',0,                          A_B_LINE,
    CONTROL('Y'),0,                 A_B_LINE,
    SK(SK_CONTROL_K),0,             A_B_LINE,
    CONTROL('P'),0,                 A_B_LINE,
    SK(SK_UP_ARROW),0,              A_B_LINE,
```

You may be able to see the pattern here: they all go back one line.  But I do not see any of that in the manual page.

Further reading:

- [Colors in Man Pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages), which mentions the environment variables.
- [lesskey(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lesskey.1.html) manual page with some discussion of key-bindings